# Parse a string into json in R

Tags: r, json, string, dataframe, parsing

My question may seem trivial, but I am facing issue while parsing a string into json format.

The string I am having is;

```
[{"Date":"2014-01-01","Turnover":"6761","Shop_Id":"60"},{"Date":"2014-02-01","Turnover":"7254","Shop_Id":"70"},{"Date":"2014-03-01","Turnover":"7539","Shop_Id":"75"},{"Date":"2014-04-01","Turnover":"8211","Shop_Id":"82"}]
```

I am not able to feed this string in R, while trying to assign this string in an object "v", I am etting this error;

```
Error: unexpected '[' in "v <- ["
```

I guess in R, it's not a standard format for a string to be started with a `"["`. I tried putting quote on the whole string to make it a character, still it's throwing the same error.

I want to parse this string as a `json` object, but unable to do the same using `fromJSON` & `toJSON`. Parsing this text, I want to make it as dataframe, where I will have all three columns viz;

```
Date   Turnover  Shop_Id
```

Please let me know using the mentioned string how can I make a dataframe by parsing the same.

TIA

Comment: Try encasing the entire JSON string in single quotes( '  ').  Then pass this variable to `fromJSON` function.

Comment: @Dave2e I tried putting a quote but still it's not taking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` to store it as string and Bingo!!!

```
    library(jsonlite)

    jsonStr <- '[{"Date":"2014-01-01","Turnover":"6761","Shop_Id":"60"},{"Date":"2014-02-01","Turnover":"7254","Shop_Id":"70"},{"Date":"2014-03-01","Turnover":"7539","Shop_Id":"75"},{"Date":"2014-04-01","Turnover":"8211","Shop_Id":"82"}]'

   fromJSON(jsonStr)
```

**Output**

```
   Date        Turnover Shop_Id
 1 2014-01-01     6761      60
 2 2014-02-01     7254      70
 3 2014-03-01     7539      75
 4 2014-04-01     8211      82
```

Comment: @Hindol Ganguly, I didn't see that *Dave2e* has already commented that. You might have missed something. Use the above, it will work for sure.

Comment: yes.. I have missed that.. Just tried & it worked.. I have upvoted @Dave2e & your's comments